# How to print out non-contiguous sections of the slice in Go?

Tags: go

Wondering if there is a way to print out non contiguous portions of slice in Gol?

**Example:**

> words := []string{"Mary","had","a","little","lamb"}

and I want to print out "**Mary**" and "**lamb"** from the slice?

Something along the lines of:

> fmt.Printf("%s\n", words[0],[5])

...which obviously this won't work... Is there a way ? :(

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're trying to do. The [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) is pretty clear about how slices can be accessed/indexed. Anything beyond that needs [to be coded yourself](https://play.golang.org/p/wTaFfWiF4i).

Answer (score 2):

You can index into the slice, you just are doing it wrong.

```
fmt.Printf("%s %s\n", words[0], words[5])
```

Your syntax for indexing didn't work because the second variable was just the index stuff without `words`. Additionally your format string was wrong, a single `%s` which means Printf is only expecting a single argument after that. Gotta have one formatter per arg.